# How to write PHP parallel cURL requests in a loop

Tags: php, for-loop, curl, parallel-processing, request

This is the code I wrote to fetch multiple URLs in parallel:

```
$nodes = array($url1, $url2, $url3);
$node_count = count($nodes);

$curl_arr = array();
$master = curl_multi_init();

for($i = 0; $i < $node_count; $i++)
{
    $url =$nodes[$i];
    $curl_arr[$i] = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_multi_add_handle($master, $curl_arr[$i]);
}

do {
    curl_multi_exec($master,$running);
} while($running > 0);


for($i = 0; $i < $node_count; $i++)
{
    $results[] = curl_multi_getcontent  ( $curl_arr[$i]  );
}
print_r($results);
```

Are the requests in the code below really sent in parallel?

```
for($i = 0; $i < $node_count; $i++)
{
    $results[] = curl_multi_getcontent  ( $curl_arr[$i]  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Certainly looks like it!

You might be able to pick up a few tips from (or just use!) [this php async class](http://gonzalo123.wordpress.com/2010/10/11/speed-up-php-scripts-with-asynchronous-database-queries/).

Comment: but with for loop i highly doubt how it can be parallel ?